# How can I make pwd resolve a soft link?

Tags: shell, symlink, pwd, cwd

On one of our servers, we have a directory with the following path:

```
"/daten/i/scripts"
```

When you go to `/daten/i`, one can see that `scripts` is a soft link to "/batch".

When I type `cd /daten/i/scripts` and then `pwd`, I see `/daten/i/scripts`.

Is there a way, a command, that I can type in at `/daten/i/scripts` that shows me that I'm in a "soft link", that I am really in `/batch`?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the -L flag to pwd should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `pwd` has `-P` (`--physical`) option to avoid all symlinks.

So do:

```
pwd -P
```

or you can use the canonical way, `readlink`:

```
readlink -f /path
```

Check `man pwd` and `man readlink`.

Comment: `man pwd` says "-P, --physical - avoid all symlinks"